# Reorder DataTable rows with comma separated values

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable `dtData`

```
ID        name
bs2       bach
js5       hash
lk3       kom
```

and I have a string `IDorder` which contains

```
js5,bs2,lk3
```

Now I want to reorder my DataTable rows by the order of ID's in `IDorder`

Expected OutPut

```
ID        name
js5       hash
bs2       bach
lk3       kom
```

How can I achieve this in C# ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string IDorder = "js5,bs2,lk3";
DataTable dtData = new DataTable();
//create columns for datatable ID and name
var ordered = dtData.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => IDorder.IndexOf(x["ID"]));
```

Comment: Nice 1. Just need to call .CopyToDataTable() method at the end to get an ordered datatable